# Recursion formula for: $a_n = \left(\frac12\right)^n+2n−1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

How do I write a recursive formula for: $$a_n = \left(\frac12\right)^n+2n−1$$ so we were taught to expand the recursion and the multiply all together. So is the answer:

$$a_1=\frac32,\quad a_n=a_{n-1}+\frac52$$

How do you show the expanding and multiplying?

Comment: Kind of, more so is that the recursive formula and starting point for the closed formula.

Comment: If you are to ask other questions on the site, could you 1. add some personal input, 2. omit the uninformative mention "discrete math" in the titles, 3. get interested in the tags you add to your questions, that are frankly subpar at present?

Comment: @Did Indeed, but why flag the *earlier* question as a duplicate?

Comment: @dxiv Because this one already had two wrong answers and I felt it was going to be easier to answer the other, more recent, question than to debunk the stuff here. Seeing what happened on the other page, this judgement call of mine may be discussed... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have $a_1=\dfrac{1}{2} + 2 - 1=\dfrac{3}{2}$

And for all $n \geq 0$, $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{1}{2}(n+1)+2(n+1)-1 = \dfrac{1}{2}n + \dfrac{1}{2} +2n+1 = \left(\dfrac{1}{2}n + 2n - 1 \right) + 2 + \dfrac{1}{2} = a_n + \dfrac{5}{2}$

Then for $n \geq 1$, $a_n=a_{n-1}+\dfrac{5}{2}$

Comment: My bad @fonfonx it's (1/2) to the nth power.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n = (\frac 12)^n + 2n − 1\\
a_{n+1} = (\frac 12)^{n+1} + 2n + 1\\
a_{n+1}=\frac12(\frac 12)^{n} + 2n + 1\\
a_{n+1}=\frac12((\frac 12)^{n} + 4n+2)=\\
a_{n+1}=\frac12((\underbrace{\frac 12)^{n} + 2n-1}_{a_n}+2n+3)=\\
a_{n+1}=\frac12(a_n+2n+3)=\\
$$ now you can be sure that $a_{n+1}$ contain a term such as $\frac12 a_n$ but you can get $$a_{n+1}=\frac12 a_n +an +b$$ 
then find a,b by initial conditions
$$a_2=\frac{1}{4}+2(2)-1 \to a_2=\frac12 (a_1)+a(2)+b\\a_3=(\frac12)^3 +2(3)-1 \to a_3=\frac{1}{2}a_2+3a+b$$
 find $a,b$ form system of equation ,finnaly you have the relation

Comment: And now, to get an answer, you should go one step further and eliminate the term $n$, thus, find a relation independent of $n$ involving $a_{n+2}$, $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$. Can you do that?

Comment: @Did Do they need to? The recurrence derived here is a perfectly legitimate, albeit inhomogeneous, answer.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki They definitely do. Otherwise, already the formula in the question would be "a perfectly legitimate, albeit inhomogeneous, answer" as well.

Comment: "find a,b form system of equation ,finnaly you have the relation" Not the relation, for the reason explained in comments.

Answer (score -1):

**This answer is probably not correct.**

Going from explicit to recursive is easy for any sequence; just compute $a_{n+1} - a_n$:

$a_{n+1} - a_n = \left[\left(\dfrac {1}{2} \right)^{n+1}+2(n+1)-1\right] - \left[\left( \dfrac {1}{2} \right)^n+2n-1 \right]$

There we go, we've already god a recursive sequence. Can you simplify it from here?

**EDIT:** To simplify $a_n-a_{n-1} = \left(\dfrac12 \right)^n - \left( \dfrac12 \right)^{n-1}+ 2$

Rewrite  $\left(\dfrac12 \right)^n$ as $\left(\dfrac12 \right)^{n-1} \cdot \left(\dfrac12 \right)^1$

$$\left(\dfrac12 \right)^{n-1} \cdot \left( \dfrac 12\right) - \left( \dfrac12 \right)^{n-1}+ 2$$

The first two terms both have $\left(\dfrac12 \right)^{n-1}$, so factor it out:

$$ \left( \dfrac {1}{2} \right)^{n-1} \left(\dfrac 12 - 1 \right) +2 $$

$\dfrac 12 - 1$ is equal to $- \dfrac 12$

$$ = \left( \dfrac {1}{2} \right)^{n-1} \left(-\dfrac 12 \right)^1 +2$$

Take the negative outside and add the powers

$$ -\left(\dfrac {1}{2} \right)^{n}+2$$

Comment: Ah we've been using $$ a_{n-1} - a_n $$ rather than  $$ a_{n+1} - a_n $$ but I guess it works both ways? I get stuck when there is $$ \frac 12^(n+1)$$ and $$ \frac 12^n$$, how does those compute?

Comment: @Kydd Well the question just asks for *a* recursive sequence, so anything involving any two terms of the sequence should be fine. If I may, I would suggest you to do it multiple ways and compare answers. As for your question, take out $\left( \dfrac {1}{2}\right)^n$ as a factor:  $\left( \dfrac {1}{2} \right)^{n+1} - \left( \dfrac {1}{2} \right)^{n} = \left( \dfrac {1}{2} \right)^{n} \left(\dfrac 12 - 1 \right) = \left( \dfrac {1}{2} \right)^{n} \left(-\dfrac 12\right)  = -\left(\dfrac {1}{2} \right)^{n+1}$

Comment: I came up with $a_n-a_{n-1} = \frac12^n - \frac12^{n-1}+ 2 $ and $ a_1 = \frac32, a_2 = \frac{13}4, a_3 = \frac{41}8, a_4 = \frac{112}{16}$. But I'm stuck here.

Comment: @Kydd If the directions just say "Find a recursive formula for this sequence", I would say you're done. If you want you can move the $a_{n-1}$ term to the other side and simplyfy the powers of $\dfrac 12$ to make it nicer.

Comment: Thanks so much @ovi. One last question, I'm rusty on factoring out when there are variables in the power. Can you refresh my mind how that works with a quick proof?

Comment: @Kydd I've edited the answer to include the factoring.

Comment: The phrase "recursion formula" is usually ttaken as referring to a formula
$$a_n=F(a_{n−1},\ldots,a_{n−k})$$ for some fixed lag $k$ and some fixed function $F$ both independent of $n$. The relation you suggest is not of this form.

Comment: @Did Thanks for letting me know, I knew there was something weird going on.

Comment: @Kydd Please see Did's comment.